# RegEx: Find string starting with "@", but not with "@@"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a RegEx to find a string starting with a single "@".

- Match: @Hello
- No match: @@Hello

I tried **"\B@\w+"**, but it also finds "@@Hello".

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [negative look-ahead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion) construct `(?!pattern)`:

```
^@(?!@)
```